# Custom table of contents numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

Two questions about customization of ToCs:

1. My document is numbered the following way: "section"-"page number inside this section". How can I get this numbering style in the ToC?
2. How to not show the page number of a certain entry in the ToC, more specifically, the bibliography (I'm not sure if it is a special case)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbib,notlof,notlot,nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.3in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\pagebreak

\begin{abstract}
Something...
\end{abstract}

\pagebreak
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thesection-\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\OldSection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\OldSection{#1}\setcounter{subsection}{-1}}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No need to add thanks, the preferred way here is to upvote any good answers you may receive; this keeps posts shorter.

Comment: The answer to your question depends, among other things, on the document class, so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My document is numbered the following way: "section"-"page number inside this section". How can I get this numbering style in the ToC?

You have specified the page format only inside `fancyfoot`. This doesn't influence the the page format itself. To change the page format you can redefine `\thepage`. Related to your needs

```
\renewcommand\thepage{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
```

To use this definition you have to know that the command `\pagenumbering` changes the definition of `\thepage` This can be seen in the default definition:

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
```

So I recommend the usage of a personal definition of `\pagenumbering`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\MyPagenumbering#1{%
   \global\c@page \@ne%page=1 
   \gdef\thepage{\thesection-\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}%page format
}
\makeatother
```

> How to not show the page number of a certain entry in the ToC, more specifically, the bibliography (I'm not sure if it is a special case)?

A simple way of doing this is the usage of the command `\addtocontents{toc}{text}`. Of course the formatting of entry must be done by the user.

---

Here your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbib,notlof,notlot,nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.3in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\MyPagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\thesection-\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\pagebreak

\begin{abstract}
Something...
\end{abstract}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{1}
\MyPagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\let\OldSection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\clearpage\MyPagenumbering{arabic}\OldSection{#1}\setcounter{subsection}{-1}}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Marco, thank you a lot, it fixed my first (and most important) question. Regarding the second, sorry for my cumbersome description, I'll try to improve it. Again, thanks!

Comment: @JoãoFernandes: I edited my answer.